# Linear-time maximum contiguous subsequence sum algorithm with a specified minimum length

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a linear-time maximum contiguous subsequence sum algorithm which assumes that the minimum subsequence length is just 0:

```
int maxSubSum4(const vector<int> & a, const int &minSeq)
{
    int maxSum = 0, thisSum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++)
    {
        thisSum += a[j];

        if (thisSum > maxSum)
            maxSum = thisSum;
        else if (thisSum < 0)
            thisSum = 0;
    }

    return maxSum;
}
```

Any hints for how this could be updated to handle positive user specified minimum subsequence lengths (`minSeq`)? I am completely stumped.

Comment: I don't think it would work in the first place when all numbers are negative.

Comment: @KelvinLai I actually believe you are correct. Would that updated functionality go hand in hand with the functionality to provide differing min subsequence values?

Comment: Yes. The logic for handling minimum subsequence length could be different for your code now and the code-to-be.

Comment: you need to modify your algorithm....i think you need to swap the `if` and `else if` conditions..try this... http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/

Comment: @SwarnavaSarkar thats a good resource, but it seems that if I do that, it still won't be able to handle all negatives in the array. And still not a solution to the min subsequence requirement. I do like Mohit Kumar's solution.

Comment: @Rdawg do you want the sum of the minimum subsequence?...or the start and end of it?....and if you want the sum then the minimum sum is zero or a negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of `minSeq` length sums, that will be your lower bound:

```
int maxSubSum5(const vector<int> & a, const int &minSeq){
  if(minSeq > a.size()) throw logic_error("maxSubSum5 - minSeq too big!");
  if(minSeq == 0) return maxSubSum4(a, minSeq);

  vector<int> minimal(a.size()-minSeq+1);
  minimal[0] = 0;
  for(size_t i=0; i<minSeq; ++i) minimal[0] += a[i];
  for(size_t i=1; i<minimal.size(); ++i) {
    minimal[i] = minimal[i-1] - a[i-1] + a[i+minSeq-1];
  }

  int maxSum = minimal[0], currentSum = maxSum;
  for(size_t i=minSeq; i<a.size(); ++i){
    currentSum += a[i];
    if(currentSum < minimal[i-minSeq+1]) currentSum = minimal[i-minSeq+1];
    if(currentSum > maxSum) maxSum = currentSum;
  }
  return maxSum;
}
```

(Whenever we reset `currentSum`, we cut off subsequence `s` where any subsequence of `s` which includes last element has negative sum.)

**Upd:** Since we use each value of `minimal` only once, they can be calculated "on the fly", without using O(N) space. This makes code shorter, as well:

```
int maxSubSum5(const vector<int> & a, const int &minSeq){
  if(minSeq > a.size()) throw logic_error("maxSubSum5 - minSeq too big!");
  if(minSeq == 0) return maxSubSum4(a, minSeq);

  int minimalSum = 0;
  for(size_t i=0; i<minSeq; ++i) minimalSum += a[i];

  int maxSum = minimalSum, currentSum = minimalSum;
  for(size_t i=minSeq; i<a.size(); ++i){
    currentSum += a[i];
    minimalSum += a[i] - a[i-minSeq];
    if(currentSum < minimalSum) currentSum = minimalSum;
    if(currentSum > maxSum) maxSum = currentSum;
  }
  return maxSum;
}
```

Comment: +1.  I think the main thing that needs to be proven, though, is that if we "reset currentSum", then it's always safe to reset it to minimal[i-minSeq+1] without trying to grow this leftward again.  Any solution at position i either uses a[i-minSeq+1] or not, so we can take the best solution in each category and compare them.  In the latter case, the solution is necessarily the single length-minSeq solution.  In the former case, we need to find a subsequence of maximum value having length >= minSeq+1 and ending at position i. ...

Comment: ... Let x[j] be the score of the length-j sequence ending at position i-1: then what we want is max(x[j]+a[i]) over all j >= minSeq.  But a[i] is fixed, so this is the same as max(x[j])+a[i] over all j >= minSeq, and we already know the first term from the optimal solution for position i-1.  Thus we don't actually have to do any further scanning in this case.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I didn't provide proof for statement in parentheses, but it's fairly obvious: let's suppose ``s`` can be represented as ``n||p``, where ``p`` has positive sum. Then, since ``s`` itself has negative sum, ``n`` has negative sum. But then we would cut it off earlier (when our sequence was ``n||(minSeq elements)``) - but we didn't, which is a contradiction. Thus, any tail of ``s`` has negative sum and ``s`` can be safely discarded.